# retain all data when editing using a django formset

Tags: django, formset

Suppose I have a model **FooBar** containing two fields *Foo* and *Bar*. Then if I use a modelform to edit just the *Foo* field for existing records, I can retain the *Bar* data by using instance, i.e.

```
foobar = FooBar.objects.get(...)
foobar_form = FooBarForm(request.post, instance=foobar)
```

What is the equivalent of this for formsets? So far I have tried Instance, which Django tells me doesn't exist for formsets, and initial, which I use to populate the formset in the GET request,

```
foobar = FooBar.objects.filter(...)
foobar_formset = FooBarFormSet(request.post, initial = foobar.values())
```

Excluding the initial argument makes has_changed() always return True, while including the initial argument makes has_changed() reflect the actual state of the form POST data. This suggests to me that the *bar* field data is picked up somewhere, yet when I iterate over foobar_formset and do

```
for foobar_form in foobar_formset:
    foobar_form.save()
```

I get an error from the debugger saying null value in column "Bar" violates not-null constraint. DETAIL: Failing row contains ('foo_value', null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a `queryset`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset

[Trying to pass a QuerySet as initial data to a formset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721066/trying-to-pass-a-queryset-as-initial-data-to-a-formset)